# setOnClickListener for a button

Tags: android, buttonclick

Just getting started with Android development and I can't figure out why this won't work. Here is the error that I am getting (on the last line):

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View
>   is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

And here is the code. Seems pretty simple, but I don't see what the problem is. Can anyone help? Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myActivity);

        View continue = findViewById(R.id.ContinueBtn);
        continue.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

When you pass `this object into setOnClickListener` then you need to implement `OnClickListenere` .

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   /// code
}
```

Comment: That's all it took. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first of all change the `continue` to some other name as it is the keyword you can't  give a keyword as variable name

implements OnClickListener for your `Mainactivity`

```
Button continuea = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ContinueBtn);
```